# terminal not working it wont let me put in my password

Tags: command-line

after I type in a command in to the terminal it ask for my password but when 
i try to type in my password nothing happens don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional whenever you type in your password from the command line it won't show the characters for security sakes, but the terminal is receiving input continue to type in your password as normal then hit enter and you shouldn't have any issues.